# How to pull data from JIRA using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, jira

I want to pull the Data from my **JIRA** account using **JS**, as I want to automate a thing i.e. **Time Tracking**.

It will track the time whether the existing resources have sufficient time/bandwidth to deliver the upcoming JIRA Tickets or not.

Kindly Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [REST-API of JIRA](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/) in combination with [angular http client](https://angular.io/guide/http). This is one of the first tutorials you already should have done with angular.

Edit Because of Comments:
JIRA REST API and JQL should work. it should look like this:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'http://my-url/rest/api/2/search?jql=' +
    'reporter=reporterXY' +
    '&amp;project=projectXY'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
}, function errorCallback() {
    console.log("Error calling API")
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the appropriate solution but can it be done using JQL (JIRA Query Language) in JS?

Comment: You said you just want to PULL data from your Jira server, that should work with a simple GET-Call to the  JIRA REST API with a JQL-string. Edited my answer.